# PHP encode_json - how to break each encoded row into a new line?

Tags: php, json, php-5.6

How can I break a new line on each JSON encoded row?

For instance,

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Specify your sqlite database name and path //
$dir = 'sqlite:testDB.sqlite3';

// Instantiate PDO connection object and failure msg //
$dbh = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open database");

// Define your SQL statement //
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";

// Iterate through the results and pass into JSON encoder //
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //var_dump($row);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

result (all rows in one line),

```
{"ID":"1","NAME":"Paul","AGE":"32","ADDRESS":"California","SALARY":"20000.0"}{"ID":"2","NAME":"Allen","AGE":"25","ADDRESS":"Texas","SALARY":"15000.0"}{"ID":"3","NAME":"Teddy","AGE":"23","ADDRESS":"Norway","SALARY":"20000.0"}{"ID":"4","NAME":"Mark","AGE":"25","ADDRESS":"Rich-Mond ","SALARY":"65000.0"}{"ID":"5","NAME":"David","AGE":"27","ADDRESS":"Texas","SALARY":"85000.0"}{"ID":"6","NAME":"Kim","AGE":"22","ADDRESS":"South-Hall","SALARY":"45000.0"}
```

But I am after (break every row into a new line),

```
{"ID":"1","NAME":"Paul","AGE":"32","ADDRESS":"California","SALARY":"20000.0"}
{"ID":"2","NAME":"Allen","AGE":"25","ADDRESS":"Texas","SALARY":"15000.0"}
{"ID":"3","NAME":"Teddy","AGE":"23","ADDRESS":"Norway","SALARY":"20000.0"}
{"ID":"4","NAME":"Mark","AGE":"25","ADDRESS":"Rich-Mond ","SALARY":"65000.0"}
{"ID":"5","NAME":"David","AGE":"27","ADDRESS":"Texas","SALARY":"85000.0"}
{"ID":"6","NAME":"Kim","AGE":"22","ADDRESS":"South-Hall","SALARY":"45000.0"}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to do. If you simply want to `echo` your JSON, just put a `<br/>` at the end of your `echo`.

Something like:

```
echo json_encode($row) . "<br/>";
```

Or just add a line break `\n` with double quotes.

```
echo json_encode($row) . "\n";
```

Or even, make it a paragraph with `<p></p>`

```
echo "<p>" . json_encode($row) . "</p>";
```